# Making a shaking leaf ball character

Tags: particles, physics, force-fields

Currently I am making a character which is a leaf ball. Everything looks great until I try to rotate it with armature.

I use hair particles to create leaves and cover it on a sphere. When the sphere rotates, leaves will shake a bit, or I can use force field to make it wiggle.

[image]

But the fact is when the sphere rotates, leaves rotate strangely. I do some researches and discover that when particles' rotation orientation axis is set to normal, particles will be rotated while the mesh rotate.

[image]

I try to use emitter as well but particles can't stick well on surface and thus it fails.

A leaf ball that can perfectly follow sphere movement and at the same time leaves itself can be shook is what I want. Is there any other ways to create similar effect?

File: [image]